# How to circumvent the "foreground lock timeout" to activate my window?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, timeout, foreground

I'm trying to make an application like Launchy/Enso/etc., which pops up when the user presses the Caps Lock key.

To do this, I have needed to install a low-level keyboard hook (`WH_KEYBOARD_LL`), from which I subsequently spawn a thread to display the dialog to present to the user.

The trouble is, when I somehow steal focus (e.g. by clicking on another window) and subsequently press Caps Lock with a short delay, my window doesn't get the keyboard input: the input goes to the background window, *even though my window is "active"* (from looking at the title bar).

Of course, this gets pretty annoying, since I then end up typing something like *"visu"* (for "Visual Studio") inside a text processor (or a chat box...) and pressing Enter, withotu realizing that it didn't do what I intended.

(Funny thing is, after a 3-second (or so) pause, my window's title bar suddenly becomes "inactive", even though it was never active in the first place!)

How can I bypass this "protection" mechanism to *actually* activate my window?

Comment: Raymond Chen covered this on Old New Thing... you need to use the shell hotkey feature instead of trying to steal the focus.

Comment: @BenVoigt: How do I do that with Caps Lock while suppressing the input?

Comment: I suggest you start by reading Raymond's entire "arms race" series.  [Here's the one I referred to already](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/02/26/9445006.aspx).

Comment: @BenVoigt: I've read those... but like I said, this doesn't tell me how to suppress Caps Lock correctly while also handling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I finally figured out a hack. (Microsoft employers: please look away...)

I intercept Caps Lock with a low-level keyboard hook, then when I detect `VK_CAPITAL`, I call

```
keybd_event(
    VK_OEM_8,
    (BYTE)MapVirtualKey(pKBDLLHook->vkCode, MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC),
    (wParam == WM_KEYUP || wParam == WM_SYSKEYUP) ? KEYEVENTF_KEYUP : 0,
    0
);
```

from within the handler.

Essentially, I just change the request to `VK_OEM_8`.
However, Notice that the virtual-key code does **not** correspond to the scan code. This is intentional -- `VK_OEM_8` doesn't *have* a scan code (as far as I could tell, anyway) so I didn't have much of an option.

Then I just program based on `VK_OEM_8` instead -- which is easy to intercept/handle/etc.

Hope this helps out other people.